# How i can set "-" instead of "•" in list of MS Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

How I can change the bullets in a list? I want to set - instead of black filled circles.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the small arrow next to the list icon above you will get a menu where you can choose the list style. There are several styles available, including one with `-`.